# Change the width of a <div> when clicked without JavaScript?

Tags: css, dynamic

I'm using a "windowed layout" (that is, the content inside certain divs look like in-browser windows, for a web-app look), and I'd like for the following function:

- When a div is clicked, it gets smaller so as to not take up space. When it is clicked again it re-expands.

This is an example for a simple page with two `<div>`s:

Suppose `<div id="window1">` and `<div id="window2">`

```css
#window1 {
    width: 30px;
}

#window1:active {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Problem is, once the mouse button is let go of, the width returns to its original size.

---

Basically the page has a little menu at the bottom left of the screen (`fixed`) that I would like to get out of the way for people with smaller resolutions (1024 and under) because it will get in the way of the text.

Comment: @AlexW I'm the divs visually look like windows inside the browser is what I meant. Also, I fixed the hover first problem. -- My issue now is making the change in width stick (after clicking on the `div:active` element, it instantly returns to its original size when it is unclicked. I'll rewrite my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it using :target - http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/V6pJT/3/

Html

```
<div class="block">
    <a class="open" href="#menu"></a>

    <div id="menu">
        Menu Item 1<br />
        Menu Item 2<br />
        Menu Item 3<br />
        Menu Item 4<br />
        Menu Item 5<br />
        Menu Item 6<br />
        Menu Item 7<br />
        <a class="close" href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block {
    position: relative;
}

#menu{
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#menu:target {
    background: orange;
    width: 200px;
}

.open,
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}

.close {
    display: none;
}

#menu:target .close {
    display: block;
}
```

​Unfortunately this solution makes the page jump every time you click it. It's unnecessarily big too. A solution taking advantage of the :checked selector would require much less html and css and it also wouldn't have the page jump on every click. Here's that solution, and the one I recommend:

The HTML...

```
<div class="block">
    <label for="toggle"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>

    <div id="menu">
        Menu Item 1<br />
        Menu Item 2<br />
        Menu Item 3<br />
        Menu Item 4<br />
        Menu Item 5<br />
        Menu Item 6<br />
        Menu Item 7<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

...and the CSS...

```
.block { 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

#toggle {
    display: none;
}

label[for="toggle"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}

#menu{
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#toggle:checked ~ #menu {
    background: orange;
    width: 200px;
}
```

​

​

Comment: Forgot to add `position: relative` to `.block`. It's there now.

Comment: perfect! I'll play with these. -- I wasn't even aware of `:target` and  `:checked` pseudo-class.

Comment: Is there a way to use this technique when, say, `#menu` and `#toggle` are not siblings or adjacent? (similar to "target" but without the drawback) -- I'm using radio buttons instead of checkboxes for the different box sizes (min, small, large). This is a really cool feature.

Comment: The chaining must start with a sibling/adjacent selector, since radio buttons or checkboxes can't have any kind of children. But you could target, for example, a children of a sibling of the :checked element like so `input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ p`. Or `input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ p a > span:last-child`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:target` pseudo selector - http://jsfiddle.net/V6pJT/

```
#menu{
    display: none;
}

#menu:target {
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}​
```